# what is RPC_READY property in cassandra nodetool gossipinfo output

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a cassandra cluster of multiple nodes. When I do 'nodetool gossipinfo'. I see that 1 node has RPC_READY value different than others. All other nodes share the same value. Can anyone explain it to me what this property is and if is there any problem if the value is different on one node? I am using cassandra version 2.2.8.

I would appreciate the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before 2.2 when a node goes up it would be broadcasted to all the nodes that its now in an UP state. This occurred sometimes before CQL was ready. The drivers listened for events like changes in state, when the node went up the drivers would try to connect to that node.

If they tried before CQL was ready the connection would fail and trigger a backoff which greatly increased time to connect to now up nodes. This caused the drivers state to be flipped from UP to DOWN with a bunch of log spam. The RPC_READY is a state that tracks if the node is actually ready for drivers to connect to. Jira [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8236) where it was added. In current version at least (I haven't looked at 2.2) the RPC_READY can change to false when being shutdown (drain) or when a node is being decommissioned as well.

Comment: Is it ok to have different values of RPC for different nodes in the same cluster?

Comment: yes, its only expected in specific scenarios though

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response.